# collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault] in qemu arm ubuntu disk image based compile

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, segmentation-fault, qemu

I am using Ubuntu disk image for ARM architecture in Qemu and trying to compile a c language program. It produces the following error message during its compile:

```
collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
make: *** [myprog] Error 1
```

Any help?

Comment: @Stefano Sanfilippo How did you eventually solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any help?

This is a bug in either `ld`, or in `qemu`.

You'll need to contact your upstream toolchain provider with a bug report, or try newer versions of binutils and `qemu` (and hope the bug has been fixed).

Comment: newer version did not fix the problem.